# Writing a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I try to write a .bat file with the following command-line

```
C:\Programme\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick mogrify -path C:\temp\size -resize 21.15% -compress LZW *.tif
```

I create it the following way:

- Open MS Editor
- insert the text
- save as `xy.bat`

When I run the `xy.bat` the “%” from "21.15%" is gone. What went wrong?

Comment: Why is the command in your image different from the command in the text of your question?

Comment: Try doubling the percent sign. This is a special character in batch files. It’ll work if you specify ‘21.15%%’. (Quotes then not needed). For example, %1, %2, %3, ... refer to command line parameters. %0 refers to the batch file. Then you have environment variables which are referred to as %varName%, %otherVarName%, etc.

Comment: It works. The funny thing is, that it also works when I copy the command-line into the ms prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see what is going wrong as your example and command line don't match, however, try putting single quotes around the parameter value:

```
C:\Programme\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick mogrify -path C:\temp\size -resize '21.15%' -compress LZW *.tif
```

Examples from the Image Magick website on command line image geometry arguments:  https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry